# Code Contracts + SharpDevelop

Tags: c#, .net, sharpdevelop

As I know according to  [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/103779/Introducing-Code-Contracts) article for using Code Contracts at runtime there is need to download rewriter and enable it via Visual Studio

My question is : is there some problem to use it with SharpDevelop (In v5.1 I have not found any related setting ) ? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Probably you would need to do using some command in CLI...

Comment: SharpDevelop is not Visual Studio. Please download and use Visual Studio Community edition if possible.